# How to match Sheet (tab) names to a range in a separate sheet and return specific text to each sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. One sheet has 2 columns of data. This sheet is titled "Notes" while the rest of them have a title that matches values entered in range A1:A6 of the "Notes" sheet. Column B contains notes that must go on each respective sheet from column A.

For example, if the 2nd sheet in the workbook is titled "Gpu manufacturing" and the value in A1 of the "Notes" sheet is also "Gpu manufacturing," then I want value in cell B1 of the "Notes" to be entered into cell F1 of the "Gpu manufacturing" sheet.

Next, if the 3rd sheet in the workbook is titled "Tesla GPUs" and the value in A2 of the "Notes" sheet is also "Tesla GPUs," then I want value in cell B2 of the "Notes" to be entered into cell F1 of the "Tesla GPUs" sheet.

Rinse and repeat to keep pulling data from the "Notes" sheet into other sheets based on their name or title.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub example() 

    Dim wkSht As Worksheet

    For Each wkSht In Sheets

        For Each Cell In Sheets("Reporting").Range("B2:B200")

            If Cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then

                wkSht.Range("D15").Copy Destination:=Cell.Offset(0,1)

            End If

        Next Cell

    Next wkSht

End Sub
```

Edit for BruceWayne:

this is what my VBA app shows:

[image: VBA window]

Comment: "...is not working" - how so? Does it give you an error (if so, what error and where?), does it run, just not accomplish what you're expecting, etc.?  Also, another idea is to load all the worksheet names into an array, then just loop through that array, instead of changing the actual sheet every time?

Comment: Hey Bruce! no, when i click run, no errors, just click and nothing happens, nothing changes

Comment: i should add, this is my first foray into VBA so i maybe doing something wrong. the code above is something i pulled off of another question. Logically, to me it seems to make sense, but when i replace sheet names and cell ranges with mine, it does not run, it seems.

Comment: Try Worksheets(wkSht.Name).Range("F1") = Cell.Offset(0, 1)

Comment: @user3359706 thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first wrote:

*"For example, if the 2nd sheet in the WB is titled "Gpu manufacturing" and the value in A1 of the "Notes" sheet is also "Gpu manufacturing," then I want value in cell B1 of the "Notes" to be entered into cell F1 of the "Gpu manufacturing" sheet."*

From which it derives the following code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Notes").Range("A1:A6")
        Worksheets(cell.Value).Range("F1") = cell.Offset(,1)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Then you wrote in a comment to BruceWayne answer:

*"however it still does not return anything in the F2 cell of each sheet"*

Which changes (from "F1" to "F2") the destination cell in sheets other than "Notes" where to paste its values from column "B"

Should this latter be the real case then just substitute:

```
Worksheets(cell.Value).Range("F1") = cell.Offset(,1)
```

with:

```
Worksheets(cell.Value).Range("F2") = cell.Offset(,1)
```

Finally you wrote in another comment to BruceWayne answer:

*"this is just a test workbook to get a macro that works because in reality, i will need to use it on a workbook that has 700+ sheets to match to a column and return specific data for that sheet from the second column on the "Notes" sheet – William Crawford 1 hour ago"*

Which is an entirely different thing

My code here answers your original question

Should your need have changed than post another question

Comment: hi there, thank you for trying to help me. When i put your code in, i get a "Runtime 9" error and debugging it highlights the following line

`Worksheets(cell.Value).Range("F2") = cell.Offset(, 1)`

because F2 on all other sheets is where i need the value to go. Any ideas on the error? should i keep the 0 in the offset parenthesis?

Comment: It means that there's no such worksheet in currently active workbook named after the current cell value. When you hit the error click "debug" and type in the immediate window "?cell.Value" press return, see what it returns and finally check if the currently active workbook has any sheet named after that value

Comment: @WilliamCrawford, did you get through it?

Comment: oh sorry, just got to work. no, when i get the error, i click debug, and it doesnt give me any additional windows, just highlights the line where the error occurs, i guess?

Comment: to pop Immediate Window out just press "Ctrl-G". Then do what I told you in previous comment and let me know.

Comment: ah ok, its GPU manufacturing in the immediate window. Let me know what else i can tell ya!

Comment: so everything's ok now?

Comment: @user3598756 - The real issue was the sheet names had trailing spaces. Once that was fixed, it should be all good.

Comment: @BruceWayne, I see... Trailing spaces should be declared outlaw worldwide!

Comment: @user3598756 oh man, if only. I can't count the times that I troubleshooted a formula for an hour or two, only to discover the issue was a stupid space.

Comment: @BruceWayne and if you had looked around you would have seen me there, too!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub example()
Dim wkSht   As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range

For Each wkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cel In Sheets("Reporting").Range("B2:B200")
        If cel.Value = wkSht.Name Then
            wkSht.Range("D15").Copy Destination:=cel.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next cel
Next wkSht

End Sub
```

Mainly, I added `Acitveworkbook.Worksheets` instead of just `Sheets`. This should make sure the active book is the one being run on.  Also, make sure you have a sheet called "Reporting". If this doesn't work, let me know how so.

Also realize, it's going to loop through 200 cells, on *each* worksheet. Is that the most efficient way to do this? Are you doing that big loop because the value is somewhere in that range? Or you actually need to check each one? (I'm thinking a `find` might be better)

Edit: How's this one, I switched it after your comments:

```
Sub example2()
Dim wkSht   As Worksheet
Dim cel     As Range
Dim curShtName As String

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Name = Trim(sht.Name)
Next sht

For i = 1 To 6               ' Since we go from A1/B1 to A6/B6
    curShtName = Worksheets("Notes").Cells(i, 1).Value
    If curShtName <> "Notes" Then
        Worksheets(curShtName).Cells(2, 6).Value = Worksheets("Notes").Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Edit: just realized this is basically what user3598756 did :P

Edit 3: Okay, first, make *positive* that the second code bit I added above is in a workbook module in the workbook with your sheets.  This should work for you, it did for me:
[image]

Then after running it:

[image]
[image]

etc, etc.

Per your most recent comments:

```
Sub copyInfo()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim notesWS As Worksheet

Set notesWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Notes") ' This is the worksheet with the info. you want to copy over to other sheets
lastRow = notesWS.Cells(notesWS.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Assuming your Col. B has the most info

Dim myFacts() As Variant
myFacts = notesWS.Range(notesWS.Cells(1, 2), notesWS.Cells(lastRow, 2))

Dim i As Long
i = 1
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Notes" Then
        ws.Cells(2, 6).Value = myFacts(i, 1) 'This loops through our Array that we created above.
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! i really appreciate it however it still does not return anything in the F2 cell of each sheet. let me clarify a little: Range A1:A6 on "Notes" sheet are the sheet names, excluding the "notes" sheet, B1:B6 is the range with the data to be entered in cell F2 in each sheet excluding the "Notes." i apologize, Excel did not save my code on exit, so i had to copy/paste the code above from another thread that i got it from without replacing the red parts with my own.

Comment: this is just a test workbook to get a macro that works because in reality, i will need to use it on a workbook that has 700+ sheets to match to a column and return specific data for that sheet from the second column on the "Notes" sheet

Comment: `Sub example()
Dim wkSht   As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range

For Each wkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cel In Sheets("Notes").Range("A1:A6")
        If cel.Value = wkSht.Name Then
            wkSht.Range("F2").Copy Destination:=cel.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next cel
Next wkSht

End Sub`


is currently what i have, still no luck (replaced with ranges and sheet names from my own WB)

Comment: Hey Bruce! this one also gives the run time error 9. also, the code doesn't specify which cell to paste the data to on each subsequent sheet?
in the error, it highlights this string "Worksheets(curShtName).Cells(2, 6).Value = Worksheets("Notes").Cells(i, 2).Value" when i hover over the "Worksheets(curShtName)" it says worksheets(curShtName) = "GPU manufacturing" so its doing something

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - you're ***positive*** the Workbook has worksheets for each cell in that "workbook name range" A1:A6?  You do have a sheet called "GPU manufacturing", correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Could you kindly let me know if you set up a blank workbook like mine? So what i have is: 1st sheet titled "Notes" 2nd sheet titled "GPU manufacturing," 3rd sheet titled "Tesla GPUs," 4th sheet titled "Tegra SoC,"  5th sheet titled "Quadro Division," 6th sheet titled "ION GPUs," and 7th sheet titled "GeForce GTX." in the sheet "Notes" i have A1:A6 with names of other sheets in order, i.e. **GPU Manufacturing, Tesla GPUs**, etc. B1:B6 has different notes for each sheet, so this can be anything really for testing purposes. F2 on each sheet must have the notes data from B

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - It works for me, unless I'm missing something. See the edit.  A runtime error 9 means there's something wrong with the range chosen (either the sheet doesn't exist, the range doesn't exist, a named range doesn't exist, etc.).

Comment: i added an edit with a link to a picture to what im seeing. Any ideas? maybe im missing something in the set up? like i said im a very new to this, like started yesterday to get into it haha

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - If you can get back into the macro, when it fails, and debug, type this in the Immediate Window: `?Worksheets("GPU Manufacturing").Name` and see if it returns `GPU Manufacturing`. If you get a Subroutine Error 9, then that sheet doesn't exist in the workbook.  Also, **are there spaces** after the worksheet names? It kinda looks like the worksheets are actually called `GPU Manufacturing [with spaces here]` not `GPU Manufacturing`.

Comment: OMG THE SPACES!

thank you so much!! i think it works now. ill update if something breaks

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - Ahahahahaaha - that's your fix. Just remove the spaces from the worksheet names.  If you need those spaces, and know how many they are, then just add that to the end of the variable.  But I recommend removing them from the sheet name.

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - I added a small bit of code to the second macro, that will go through all your worksheets and `Trim` the name (remove leading and trailing spaces). You can pull that out and make it its own Sub if you want to keep the spaces.

Comment: Neato! ill definitely keep this in case there are spaces in the actual worksheet that i need to work in. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - You're welcome, glad we figured it out!

Comment: you have been so much more than helpful, i really appreciate it! this code works flawlessly in my test sheet that is really clean, however the workbook that i need to work in is really messy, so i was wondering what kind of tweaks to this code can i make in order for it not to rely on sheet names and simply copy/paste stuff consecutively onto next sheet's specified cell from a range on the notes sheet. if you cant help, its OK ill try and keep tweaking this code here. again, huge help!

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - what's the messy part, the names of sheets? There are a few other ways to tackle this probably. If you don't want to rely on sheet names, how do you know what info to put in F2 of each sheet? If you could explain a little more I don't mind taking a shot.

Comment: ave been modifying your code but its not working.  oh god, im such a noob. basically, do the same thing you did (the part about taking the value from B1 in the notes sheet and putting it into a F2, BUT ON THE NEXT sheet after Notes and so on with B2, B3 all the way to B675, regardless of what its name is. so, consecutively). and yeah, data source from which excel sheet is DL from cuts off the sheet names so they dont match the col. A in the notes sheet.

Comment: just like use Next function or something to automatically move to the next sheet and paste the very next value in the range from the notes sheet into F2. if that makes sense :P

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - See my edit, the code at the end. This is starting to creep away from your original question. Take a look at what the new code does, and see if it works. If you need to tweak it, look up like "VBA loop through worksheets", or such.  Play around and if you have more questions, it may be worth creating a new Q here.

Comment: thank you! yeah, i thought i might need a loop for that many worksheets. many thanks, ill try and see if it works

Comment: it totally works!!!!! thank you man! i wish there was like an equivalent of reddit gold on here so i can give it to you! one small question: what exactly does `myFacts` do?

Comment: @WilliamCrawford - Haha, no worries! Glad to help out.  `myFacts` is an array. There are many ways I could've tackled your question (an alternative would be to loop through your "info" range, one by one. I figured an Array would just work quicker).  Check out [Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for more info. (PS That website is a great resource for learning VBA. It's a lot of text, but it is well written and easy to follow).  This just dumps *all* of your "facts" into an array.  So `myFacts(1,1)` is the first "fact", `myFacts(2,1)` is the second fact, etc

Comment: ah, ok that makes sense. ill definetely read through Chip's website. I'm sure ill need more VBA help in the future, so ill use that instead of coming here all the time haha. again, thanks a ton, you are a life saver, sir!